# How to prohibit any response except html in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have such code:

```
def show
  @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

This code allows respond on json, but renders nothing. How to show custom page on any other request except html?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `format.any` for any other request except html:

```
def show
  @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render text: => 'This is html' }
    format.any  { render :text => "Only html is supported" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there more general solutions? Write this line is too tedious

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
before_filter do
  render text: 'Wrong type', status: 406 unless request.format == Mime::HTML
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the format of your routes when you define them in your config/routes.rb

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => {:format => :html} do
  resources :attachments
end
```

Define all the routes whose format you want to restrict within that scope.